# Probability formula for a specific case

Tags: probability

My university's exam period is 30 days long. Say I have five exams, each with an equal likelihood of being on a certain day within the period. Then for the $d$th day of the period, what is the probability that this day will be the last day on which I have an exam?

If the question was, "what is the probability that I all my exams will happen before a certain day?", then the formula would be simple: $(\frac{d}{30})^5$. But I'm having trouble with the more specific case.

Comment: On day d, you can have 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 exams. If you have n exams on day d, then there are (d-1)^(5-n) ways to schedule the other exams.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this problem can be answered without additional information.  For example, can you have more than one exam on the same day?  Are exam dates independent?

I will answer the question on the assumption that you have at most one exam per day, and that all combinations of $5$ days are equally likely.

Then the number of possible combinations of $5$ dates from $30$ is $C(30,5)$.  If the last exam to be on day $d$, then you have $C(d-1,4)$ options for the first $4$ exams.  So the required probability is
$$\frac{C(d-1,4)}{C(30,5)}$$
for $d=5,6,\ldots,30$.